# how to get my app go through the facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook

I'm not sure if my question is correct but i am having an error..at the facebook developer tools page, I provided my access token and pushed the get access token button, then I got this error

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

my site url is something like

```
http://www.example.com/fb/
```

and my domain is like

```
www.example.com
```

did i do anything wrong? and why it doesn't go through and am getting that error ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ou're trying to send the user, after login, to a domain other than the one configured for your app - check what you're passing into getLoginUri() if you're using the PHP SHK

Comment: i haven't coded anything yet, all i did was create an app and set it up from the facebook page, you mean to say, i need to code first using the PHP sdk ?

Comment: In the popup dialog for adding the app, there'll be a URL parameter of 'next' or 'redirect_uri'. If this value doesn't correlate to what's configured in your app settings in the 'Site Domain' section (Under Basic -> Website) you'll get that error